# Не могу добавить ufw в автозагрузку ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

Ufw не запускается после перезагрузки. 
Запускаю вручную:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo update-rc.d ufw defaults
```

Не помогает.

Comment: какому пакету принадлежит `/sbin/init`? (`dpkg -S /sbin/init`).

Comment: Ключ -f пробовал?

Comment: systemd-sysv: /sbin/init

Comment: systemd-sysv: /sbin/init        Если так sudo update-rc.d ufw defaults, то никаких изменений.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo systemctl enable ufw
sudo systemctl start ufw
```

Comment: После перезагрузки sudo ufw status
Состояние: неактивен

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: На вводе команд в консоли и полученном ответе. Пока ни один их представленных советов, к сожалению, не помог.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло следующее (ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS):
В файле /etc/init/ufw.conf закомментировал строки

```
#start on (starting network-interface
#          or starting network-manager
#          or starting networking)
```

Добавил в тот-же файл под закомментированными строками следующую строку:

```
start on startup
```

Плюс выполнил след.рекомендацию:

> Если у вас установлен iptables-persistent , необходимо вывести его из
>   строя. Переместить iptables-persistent из /etc/init.d и переименовать
>   все символические ссылки в rc0.d - rcS.d , сделав 1 - ю букву (S или
>   K) в нижнем регистре. (Или переместить их.)

Источник:
https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=ru&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.ru&sl=en&u=https://askubuntu.com/questions/474216/14-04-missing-etc-init-d-ufw-my-firewall-never-auto-starts&usg=ALkJrhitvrM_hGf2sT6ZnpxS42DDKZ8bSw